# T-SQL allows for cursor data type. What the Heck is a Cursor?

Tags: sql, t-sql, cursor

At [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260815(v=vs.60).aspx) there is a very lucid discussion, "What the Heck is a Cursor, Anyway" under ADO Object Model - Revisited.  But I'm thinking it has much wider application that just keeping track of "next row."  Can anyone point me toward a more complete discussion of the cursor and its use.

Answer (score 2):

"Keeping track of the next row" is a reasonable definition.

"A bridge across the ‘impedence mismatch’ between the ‘record- based’ culture of conventional programming and the set-based world of the relational databases" is another reasonable way of thinking about cursors.

Here's a good article about cursors in general:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/robyn-pages-sql-server-cursor-workbench/

Here is a good article about the specific cursor types available in MSSQL:

[MSDN: Understanding MSSQL Cursor Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378405(v=sql.110).aspx)

ADO, by the way, is obsolete.  ADO.Net - which is already 15++ years old - is a very different programming model.

I would strongly discourage you from spending too much time "learning" VB6-era ADO, unless you absolutely have to.  Here's another good article:

[MSDN: A comparison of ADO and ADO.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/904fck4k(v=vs.71).aspx)